# ERROR : Cannot find module './TransactionCard' or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, project

```
export { default } from "./TransactionCard";
```

while exporting from a tsx file getting this error.

I was trying to export a component as default from index.tsx file.

Comment: Wrong path to the file most likely

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.